# Update selected option within a Materialize dropdown form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I am relatively new to web design and coding in HTML/CSS/JavaScript, and thus I will cut to the chase.

I need to be able to create a dropdown form on part of a site I have been tasked with creating, using Materialize CSS.  So far, I have created the dropdown form and populated it with the options that the user may select from.  I am having trouble, however, making anything actually show up *inside* the form once the user has selected an option.  I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="selector">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Add Activity</option>
        <option value="1">Tree Ropes</option>
        <option value="2">Abseiling</option>
        <option value="3">Bike Scramble</option>
        <option value="4">Rafting</option>
    </select>
    <label>Choose an Activity</label>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
    $('select').append("<option></option>");
}  );
</script>
```

It is with the JQuery I feel that things begin to go awry.

Any help will be greatly appreciated and add to my knowledge, thus decreasing the number of stupid questions that I ask.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you please check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/054Lytvu/) and try to explain your problem from here? I am not sure on what your problem is.

Comment: @JohannesPiontkowitz As far as I can tell The code at your link is identical to mine (except for I had an older version of JQuery, which has since been rectified).  The problem comes when I have to select an option from the list:  I may click it; it is recognised as being selected (it does not highlight when moused over in the list), but _I cannot see it in the box_.

Comment: Does it work as you'd like it in the fiddle?

Comment: Given that the fiddle actually works, yes.

Comment: Ok so then you need to take a look at how you implement your jquery and materialize.js. You need to implement jquery **before** the materialize.js. Please check my answer and see if that works.

Comment: Make sure your select form element is in a form that you are submitting. Right now it's just in a div; won't work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to implement jquery **before** your materialize.js file.

I updated [your fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/tvyu115w/)

Here is the updated html of your select-element:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="selector" class="red-text">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Add Activity</option>
        <option value="1">Tree Ropes</option>
        <option value="2">Abseiling</option>
        <option value="3">Bike Scramble</option>
        <option value="4">Rafting</option>
    </select>
    <label>Choose an Activity</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: With the exception of the top three lines being slightly different, and my code not having a "container" div, my code is identical.  Perhaps it's my browser (Microsoft Edge).  The form completely failed to work when I added the class "browser-default".

Comment: But are your top three lines (implementing scripts and css) in the same order as they are in the fiddle?

Comment: <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>        #I have these in <head>

Comment: And these in <body> above the JQuery:    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.txt"></script>

Comment: **"js/materialize.min.txt"** looks wrong. It should have an .js file extension.

Comment: This work is partly done at school and lots of file extensions are blocked because the network administrator doesn't know what he is doing.  .txt's are copy-able.  I have made a copy of the .js version with the .js's contents in a .txt file.

Comment: Can you try it with this `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>` import please?

Comment: I have replaced:  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.txt"></script>  with the code above to no avail.  Is that what you wanted me to try?

Comment: Can you copy all of your html, including head section etc, to a new fiddle on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/) and post it here?

Comment: I have no idea if I've done this right at all but here it is:  https://jsfiddle.net/00kmkrny/17/

Comment: Ok i found the bad guy. Remove `color: #fdfdfd` from your body tag. You're setting a white text for all elements inside your body tag that do not own a `color` property. Your second option would be to add a color style for your select element. Please check the [updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/tvyu115w/). Please also check my updated answer and consider to mark it as correct.

Comment: I had a feeling that that might have been the problem; I was using this code to try to make sure it wasn't happening:  ul.dropdown-content.select-dropdown li:not(.disabled) span {     color: #ee6e73; }

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this.  I'm sorry it took so long, I'm a slow learner!  :)